# Select objects of interest and pass them to map_dfr to bind rows in R?

Tags: r, functional-programming, dplyr, purrr

I have 13000 dataframes, each look like:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1    T    4.4  3    1
3    F    23.3 4    1
353  T    1.3  2    1
34   T    0.4  1    1
```

Each df name has the following format/pattern: user_N_d; where N = 1:13000.

I thought to check for all objects created of this pattern, put them in a big vector and pass to `map_dfr` with `f = bind_rows`.

Please advise how to do this.

I have done the following so far:

```
pattern <- START %R% 
  "user" %R% "_" %R% 
  one_or_more(DGT) %R% "_" %R% "d" %R% END

user_i_d_vec <- objects() %>% str_subset(pattern)
```

But I can't pass it to `map_dfr` - they are names but not the objects I need. Please advise what should I do make it happen?

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, mget(paste0("user_", 1:13000, "_d")))`. Or `purrr::bind_rows(mget(paste0("user_", 1:13000, "_d")))`. Probably fastet way is `data.table::rbindlist(mget(paste0("user_", 1:13000, "_d")))`.

Comment: @markus why not bind_rows from dplyr? Isn't it more efficient?

Comment: It should be paste0.

Comment: Sorry, you're right of course. Corrected it.